# How do I make this request using the Windows 7 Phone SDK

Tags: windows-phone-7, networking

Hi I have the following jQuery.post example and need to know how to make this same request using the Windows 7 phone SDK.

Any suggestions or pointers would be appriciated.

```
jQuery.post('http://URL',{
      'key':'4ec6975151b8ea0d768f8599541e2ee30fb20a93',
      'function':'getGroupMembers',
      'parameters':{    
        "group":{
            'group_id':'44',
            'user_id':'100003167624583'
        }
    }      
  },
function(res){
   console.log(res);   
},'json');
```

Answer (score 0):

[`WebClient.UploadStringAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144240%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) will post a string and return the result. You can use [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) (either via NuGet or downloaded manually), to serialize/deserialize:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();

client.UploadStringCompleted += (s,e) =>
{
    var children = JToken.Parse(e.Result)["some_json_property"].Children();
    // continue here (but remember this is all asynchronous)
};

client.UploadStringAsync(
    new Uri("http://URI"),
    "POST",
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
    {
        key = "4ec6975151b8ea0d768f8599541e2ee30fb20a93",
        function = "getGroupMembers",
        parameters = new {    
            group = {
                group_id = "44",
                user_id = "100003167624583"
            }
        }
    }));
```